# Standard Topology

Tags: general-topology

I have to show the following:
Given is the standard topology in the field of real numbers, denoted as 
$$ \{U \subseteq \Bbb R: \forall u \in U \,\exists r\,(u,U) > 0, \text{ with } \{w \in \Bbb R: |u-w| < r\}\}$$
It needs to be proven that the standard topology denoted above, $\mathcal O$, holds that  $\mathcal O \subseteq \mathcal O_T$, where $\mathcal O_T$ denotes any topology for which the set $(-\infty, a) \cup (a,\infty) a \in \Bbb Q$,  is open.
What I did for now:
I showed that the intervals $(-\infty, a)$ and $(a,\infty)$ are open in $\mathcal O $.
I then defined a topology $\mathcal T$ which holds the same open intervals and now try the following.

$(a,b)$ is a basis for $\mathcal O$.
I need to deduce that since $(-\infty, a)$ and $(a,\infty)$ are open in $\mathcal T$, that every interval with rational boundaries is open in $\mathcal T$.
Any help?
Thanks very much

Comment: You should make some attempt using the properties of open sets, arbitrary union and finite intersection.

Comment: Sadly I do not have heard of arbitrary union or finite interseciton;(

Comment: Note that edits since the initial posting have changed (-$\infty$,a) $\cup$ (a,$\infty$) to $(-\infty,a) \cup (a,\infty).$ That is the proper way to write MathJax code.

Comment: How do you define a topology???

Comment: My fault, I translated the terms wrongly.

Comment: Still I do not know how to make use of your comment.

Comment: I misread the question. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

$O_T$ could be discrete, in which case O subset $O_T,$
or it could be { (-oo,a) $\cup$ (a,oo) : a in R },
which is a counterexample to what you want to prove.

Comment: How is this a counterexample?

Comment: It is a counter example to what you wrote.  It is not a counter example to what you though you wrote.

Comment: Please ignore my comment, I completely misread the question.